# show that $L(\ell_1,X) \cong \ell_\infty(X)$ via $\phi(T)(i) = T(e_i)$ holds isometrically

Tags: functional-analysis

I'd like to get a proof verification.

Suppose $\phi(T) = \phi(T')$. Then they are the same as elements in $\ell_\infty(X)$ (i.e., $\phi(T)(i)= \phi(T')(i)$ for all $i$). But then $T(e_i) = T'(e_i)$ by the definition of $\phi$. Since $T,T'$ are linear and have the same behavior on basis vectors $e_i$, $T=T'$ and $\phi$ is one-to-one. Fix $x \in \ell_\infty(X)$. Define a linear map $T$ given by $T(e_i) =x_i$ for all $i$. Then $T \in L(\ell_1,X)$ and $\phi(T)(i) = T(e_i) = x_i$ for all $i$, giving that $\phi(T) = x$. So $\phi$ is surjective and thus bijective. But for any $a,b$, $\phi(aT +bT')(i) = (aT+bT')(e_i) = aT(e_i)+bT'(e_i) = a\phi(T)(i)+ b\phi(T')(i) = (a\phi(T)+b\phi(T'))(i).$

So $\phi(aT +bT') = a\phi(T)+b\phi(T')$, $\phi$ is an isomorphism and $L(\ell_1,X) \cong  \ell_\infty(X)$.
Fix $T \in L(\ell_1,X)$. Then
\begin{align*}
 \|\phi(T)\|_{\ell_\infty(X)}
 &= \sup_i \|\phi(T)(i)\|_{X} \\
 &= \sup_i \|T(e_i)\|_{X} \\
 &= \sup_{\|x\|_{\ell_1(X)} \leq 1} \|T(x)\|_{X}\\
 &= \|T\|_{L(\ell_1,X)},
 \end{align*}
where the third line follows from that $T$ is linear $\implies$ $\|Tx\|_X$ is maximized for some basis vector $e_i$. So $\phi$ is an isometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Injectivity:** your argument is kind of fine, but you don't use that $T$ is bounded. And you need it to pass from "equal on basis elements" to "equal everywhere".

**Surjectivity:** you don't say that you extend by linearity. You don't show that $T$ is bounded. And you need this to know that you can extend from a dense subset to the whole thing.

**Linearity:** it's fine.

**Isometry:** "is maximized for some basis vector $e_i$". No. Not only is the norm not in general maximized on a basis element (even in finite dimension); it is often not a maximum.

As a general comment, your arguments never use that $\ell_1$ is $\ell_1$; that should tell you that you are glossing over something.

---

What happens here is that if $a\in\ell_1$ and $T$ is bounded, then
$$
Ta=\sum_ja_jTe_j.
$$
Using the continuity of the norm,
$$
\|Ta\|\leq\sum_j|a_j|\,\|Te_j\|\leq\sup\{\|Te_j\|:\ j\}\,\sum_j|a_j|=\|(Te_j)_j\|_\infty\,\|a\|_1=\|\phi(T)\|_\infty\,\|a\|_1.
$$
So $\|T\|\leq\|\phi(T)\|_\infty$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $j$ such that $\|\phi(T)\|_\infty<\|Te_j\|+\varepsilon$. As $\|e_j\|=1$,
$$
\|T\|\geq\|Te_j\|>\|\phi(T)\|_\infty-\varepsilon. 
$$
As this can be done for any $\varepsilon>0$, this shows the reverse inequality and then $\|T\|=\|\phi(T)\|_\infty$, which shows that $\phi$ is an isometry.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why I need $T$ bounded to pass from "equal on basis elements" to "equal everywhere"? Also, where do I need that $\ell_1$ is $\ell_1$?

Comment: When you are dealing with injectivity, you claim that because $T$ is linear and $T$ is zero in the basis elements, then $T$ is zero. Which is not true. The "basis" you use is not actually a basis; it is a Schauder basis, but not a basis. You can actually extend $\{e_j\}$ to an actual Hamel basis $\{e_j\}\cup \{f_k\}$, and define a linear operator $T$ by $Te_j=0$, $Tf_k=1$ for all $j,k$. Then $T$ is linear, zero on all your basis vectors, and nonzer; and, of course, unbounded. *(continued)*

Comment: It is important that you realize that when you do $T\Big(\sum_ja_je_j)\Big)=\sum_ja_jTe_j$, you are using the continuity of $T$.

Comment: As for "using $\ell_1$", the result you are trying to prove is not true if you replace $\ell_1$ with $\ell_2$, so you are supposed to be using it somewhere!

Comment: I realize that. I'm just confused where I need it. Is it to have that $T$ is bounded?

Comment: Your argument would apply in $\ell_2$, or any $\ell_p$ for that matter, where what you want ot show is false: if $p\ne1$, then $\phi$ is not isometric. And you never use that $T$ is bounded; if you remove the "bounded" requirement, neither your injectivity nor surjectivity arguments hold.

Comment: Can you post a detailed proof of the injectivity and surjectivity of $\phi$? It would help me understand things better.

Comment: The injectivity you don't need, because any isometry is injective. In any case, what you are missing from your injectivity argument is how to pass from $Te_j=0$ for all $j$ to $T=0$; this requires that $T$ is bounded, because you want to say that $T\big(\sum_ja_je_j\Big)=\sum_ja_jTe_j=0$.

Comment: And the problem with your surjectivity argument is that you don't show that $T$ is bounded. If the operator with $Te_j=x_j$ were to be unbounded, it's not in $L(\ell_1,X)$ and your argument doesn't go through. The reason that $Ta=\sum_ja_jx_j$ is bounded is the inequality $\|Ta\|\leq\|x\|_\infty\,\|a\|_1$, which shows that $T$ is bounded and $\|T\|\leq\|x\|_\infty$.  With a bit more work you can show that $\|T\|=\|x\|_\infty$, which is precisely the argument that shows that $\phi$ is an isometry.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I understand now. I was missing that bounded $\iff$ continuous for linear functionals, which caused some confusion.

Comment: Ok. I never thought that could be the case. The equivalence bounded/continuous is topic 1 the first day one talks about linear operators on a normed space, so I assumed you were way beyond that to be thinking about an isomorphism like the one in your question.

Comment: I did learn that a long time ago. A long enough time ago to have forgotten that fact. Thanks for the help.